# Craft Form Event - Target a Single Form

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-amforms

I'm newish to Craft CMS.

Im building a plugin for a client, one of their forms needs to post inputted data to an api then return a result to a hidden text area before the email if fired off.

I have built the form and plugin with event, only problem is this event fires with every form i have on the site now. is it possible to target a form handle in the event ?

Currently using

```
craft()->on('amForms_submissions.onBeforeSendEmail', function (Event $event) {
    $params = $event->params();
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The following code fires the onBeforeEmailSubmission event ([link)](https://github.com/am-impact/amforms/blob/master/services/AmForms_SubmissionsService.php#L351)

```
// Fire an 'onBeforeEmailSubmission' event
$event = new Event($this, array(
    'email'      => $notificationEmail,
    'submission' => $submission,
));
$this->onBeforeEmailSubmission($event);
```

So you'll have access to the `$submission` and to the `$email` as array keys in your `$params` variable. In order to get the form you have to [do](https://github.com/am-impact/amforms/blob/master/models/AmForms_SubmissionModel.php#L65)

```
$submission = $params['submission'];
$form = $submission->getForm();
if($form->handle === 'whatever'){
     // do something
}
```